# I want to test 'Crittercism' tool, how can i develop a crashing app for android?

Tags: android, crash, crittercism

I want to develop a basic app for Android which must crash randomly to test 'crittercism' tool. What must i do to make an app crash?

Thanks.

Comment: LOL, that's easy.  Just cause a NullPointerException.

Comment: How may i create a NullPointerException in my android code?

Comment: Just throw any `RuntimeException` to make your app crash.

Comment: What @laalto said.  Like `throw new Exception("oops");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set something to null and try to use it, like:

```
TextView v;
v.setText("X");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I laughed because there are so many questions on SO, where people ask "why did my app crash", and that is the reason.

Comment: i see, who wants his app to crash you thought.. i am new to android tools and want to discover how things work with crittercism..

Comment: Hey again. Is there any alternative ways to make app crash?

Comment: @ufukcakir Just search for crashes in the `[android]` tag here. There are about a million and one ways to make it crash.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite few questions about this on SO, and most of the answers suggest creative ways to do something illegal that triggers the exception. I believe they are not practical, especially if you want to test for different types of exceptions.

The right way to do it is:

```
throw new RuntimeException("some message");
```

or for specific ones:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("some message");
throw new NullPointerException("some message");
throw new ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException("some message");
throw new ClassCastException("some message");
...
```

See: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/RuntimeException.html

You can do the same with any [checked type](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Exception.html) of exceptions to test your exception handling (try/catch).